# .NET Core 2.1 How to provide nuget packages to a heavily modularized deployment with shared runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

Setup:

- single offline (blocked from inet) server
- multiple applications
- apps load .net core assemblies (plugins with their own assembly or nuget deps) at runtime through reflection

Problem: What is the most efficient way to deploy the application set?

Currently I publish application per application, so that all required nuget packages and assemblies are available. However, this means the complete .net core and asp.net assembly set is copied over multiple times.
To have a shared deployment with an installed .net core runtime or sdk, there does not seem to be an easy way to make the required nuget packages available on an offline machine?

Any suggestions on the best-practices setup for these kind of deployments?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use the [global packages folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders).

If your projects use `PackageReference` they consume their dependencies directly out of that folder instead of copying them locally, so if you're worried about disk space that would be a way to avoid duplication if that's what you're really worried about.